# If maximal tori are self centralizing in $R(G)$, why do Levi subgroups exist?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected algebraic group, $L$ a connected subgroup.  We say that $L$ is a **Levi subgroup** of $G$ if the product map $L \times R_u(G) \rightarrow G$ is an isomorphism of varieties.

Then $L$ is necessarily reductive, the restriction of $G \rightarrow G/R_u(G)$ to $L$ is a bijective morphism of algebraic groups, $R(L) = Z(L)^0$ is a maximal torus of $R(G)$, and $R(L)$ can be recovered as $L \cap R(G)$.

The following proposition is from Borel, *Linear Algebraic Groups*.

[image]

I understand the proof of (i), but (ii) I do not at all.  Borel does not give a proof of (ii).  He just says it follows from (i) and the following two facts:

> Let $H$ be a connected solvable group.
>
> (1) Maximal tori in $H$ are conjugate under $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} C^n$, where $C^1 \supseteq C^2 \supseteq \cdots$ denotes the descending central series.
>
> (2) If $S \subseteq H$ is a subgroup of $H$ consisting of semisimple elements, then $S$ is contained in a torus, and $Z_G(S)$ is connected and equal to $N_G(S)$.

I don't understand how (ii) follows so easily.  I let $T$ be a maximal torus of $R(G)$, and I'm trying to show that the product map  $Z_G(T) \times R_u(G) \rightarrow G$ is an isomorphism of varieties.

So far, all I've got is that $Z_G(T) \cap R_u(G)$ is trivial.  This is because of the hypothesis that $T = Z_{R(G)}(T) = Z_G(T) \cap R(G)$, whence $Z_G(T) \cap R_u(G)$ is a unipotent group contained in $Z_G(T) \cap R(G) = T$, which implies that $Z_G(T) \cap R_u(G)$ is both diagonalizable and unipotent, hence trivial.

Comment: I think your definition of Levi subgroup might be incorrect.

Comment: What's the correct definition?  I thought I was using Borel's definition in his book

Comment: A parabolic subgroup $P \subset G$ is one such that the quotient is a projective variety, a Levi subgroup $L \subset P$ is one that is isomorphic to the maximal reductive quotient of $P$. For example $L=\operatorname{GL}_2 \times \operatorname{GL}_1 \subset \operatorname{GL}_3$ is the Levi subgroup associated to the parabolic consisting of $2 \times 1$ block upper triangular matrices.

Comment: It's sort of an abuse of definition that we call $L = \operatorname{GL}_2 \times \operatorname{GL}_1$ a Levi subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_3$.  The original definition, which I'm using, would say that $L$ is a Levi subgroup of a parabolic subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_3$, not a Levi subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_3$ itself.  You don't need the ambient $\operatorname{GL}_3$ or any notion of parabolic subgroup thereof, to define "Levi subgroup of a connected linear algebraic group."

Comment: See for example here http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/249BW16Page/handouts/levi.pdf

Comment: Well Borel is certainly using the terminology the way I'm using it.

Comment: I have attached a picture of the definition of Levi subgroup from Borel's book, so you can see for yourself https://imgur.com/a/zUNBNt9